# Quick question about the definition of Simple Modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, definition

The following is taken from "Modules an approach to linear algebra" by Blyth

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

$\textbf{Exercise:}$

An $R$-module $M$ is said to be $\textit{simple}$ if it has no submodules other than $M$ and $\{0\}.$  Prove that $M$ is simple if and only if $M$ is generated by every non-zero $x\in M.$

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

Should the beginning phrasing of the question be "[A]n unitary $R$-module $M$ is said to be simple..." instead of just "[A]n $R$-module $M$ is said to be simple...."  The point when simple modules are discussed, must it contain the identity element?  Sometimes I just see "A simple module...." instead of A unitary simple module...."  Specifically in cases where one is asked to show that $M$ is a simple module in $R$ if and only if it satisfies certain condition.  So assuming that it satisfies certain condition, then to show that $M$ is a simple module in $R$ requires one to show that $1_Rx=x$ for all $x\in M$.   I am sorry if I am asking something obvious.  I just want to make sure my gut feeling about this definition is correct.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @DietrichBurde does simple module imply that the module contains the identity element.  In Blyth's text, he calls a ring with an idenity element to mean unitary ring.  Beyond issue of terminology convention, a simple module $M$ in $R$ means that $R$ is a unitary ring?

Comment: @DietrichBurde so basically i can safely assume that a simple module contains the unit element in its underlying ring even though if it doesn't get mentioned?

Comment: Yes, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)). In all cases I have seen this was the case.

Comment: @DietrichBurde ah kk.  Thank you for the clarification.  :)

Comment: The definition is wrong. The zero module is not simple. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/too+simple+to+be+simple

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg actually I saw in a text that the zero module is not simple.  Why is that?  Don't the zero module only contain the set zero?

Answer (score 2):

> must it contain the identity element?

Contain? No, that doesn't make any sense.  "unitary right $R$ module" means that $m\cdot 1_R=m$ for all $m\in M$, where $1_R$ is the identity of $R$.

> (The implied question) Is it likely all modules are considered unitary?

Yes.  In very rare occasions they might not, but in such case the author would be explicit about it.

If you really are interested in non-unitary modules, you can look at this:

If $M$ is a (possibly nonunitary) right module over a ring $R$ with identity $1$, then $M= M\cdot 1\oplus \mathrm{Ann}_M(1)$, where $M\cdot 1:=\{m\cdot1\mid m\in M\}$ is clearly a unitary $R$ module.

Comment: @rschieb why is $M\cdot 1:=\{m\cdot1\mid m\in M\}$ a non-unitary module?   How is it consider non-unitary. I think I am confused over a module by default containing the idenity of its underlying ring, versus being non-unitary.

Comment: @Seth I didn't say it was non-unitary.   The last line of my post says "$M\cdot 1:=\{m\cdot1\mid m\in M\}$ is clearly a unitary $R$ module."  It looks like you are confusing the terms "unitary subring" with "unitary module."  For modules we just want the identity of the ring to act like an identity on the elements of $M$. By no means does it have to _contain_ the identity to do that.

Comment: what is a "non-unitary modules" then?  I am now even more confused by the existence of such term.

Comment: @Seth What is "non-unitary module"?  You just negate the definition I gave you. It means a module $M$ for which $1_R$ does _not_ act like the identity on $M$. For example, if you take an abelian group $M$ and define $mr=0$ for all $m\in M$, $r\in R$.

Comment: in your example, if $M$ is the abelian group and define $mr=0$ for all $m\in M, r\in R,$  Then $M$ is still consider as a module because $1_Rm=m$?   I still don't see how it is non unitary. Also Martin Brandenburg stated above that zero is not a simple module.  That is so weird.  As a single element set and as a module, the only submodule is itself.

Comment: _I still don't see how it is non unitary._  Well, let's check if $1_Rm=m$ for all $m$.  Let's pick any nonzero $m$. Well, $1_Rm:=0$ by our definition of the module action.  Since $1_Rm\neq m$, the module isn't unital.  See?

Comment: The zero module is not a simple module because it is not useful to allow them to be.  One way to define a simple module is that it has exactly two submodules: the trivial ones.

Comment: ah ok ok.  By the way, non unitary module has its use in algebra besides just being some sort of an artifice.  It is just strange to see such example.  Feels like one of those strange examples in algebra.

Comment: @Seth One way to think of the requirement of a module being unital is that the associated ring homomorphism $R\to End_{\mathbb Z}(M)$ maps the identity of $R$ to the identity of $End_{\mathbb Z}(M)$.

Comment: ah kk. That make more sense to me now.  Thank you so much for the insight.